After writing n decimal values into a binary file with append mode, the file size is 16 bytes instead of 16n bytes
This code is for developing a WinForm program instead of a CLI program.
string regexSearch = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
string filename = data_dir + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss") + ".bin";
Regex regex = new($"[{Regex.Escape(regexSearch)}]");
using (FileStream fs = new(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
using (BinaryWriter writer = new(fs))
{
    foreach(Control item in Controls)
    {
        if (item is TextBox box)
        {
            decimal current = 0;
            try { current = Convert.ToDecimal(box.Text); }
            catch (Exception) { /* do nothing */ };
            writer.Write(current);
        }
        else if (item is NumericUpDown numberbox) writer.Write(numberbox.Value);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("File saved to " + filename + ".", Text,
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

}

In the program there are more than 10 TextBox or NumericUpDown controls (if a textbox is empty, decimal value 0.0m will be written and appended into the file) but after the code above executed, the size of the binary file is only 16 bytes instead of 16n bytes expected.
I've tried to use fs.Close() explictly but it doesn't work.

Can you provide a [mcve] which reproduces the problem? It seems very unlikely that you need both WinForms and the file part to see the problem. I suspect that either your loop isn't finding all the items, or you could reproduce the problem with just hardcoded data. I would suggest using a debugger to start with - see how often you're actually hitting writer.Write.

Do all these Controls have the same Parent Container (a Form, it appears)? -- (unrelated) Replace Convert.ToDecimal() with decimal.TryParse() -- What's the Regex for? If it has no use here, remove it, it's just a distraction

Do the values need to be saved in some order such that the program can retrieve them in the same order? If so, it would be better to save the values as {key, value} pairs.

Have you stepped through the program to see if the loop is processing all of your controls? (Controls are stored in a hierarchy. foreach (var control in Controls) will only process controls directly in the form, not ones held in Panels and other containers.)

Looking at the code, which is good enough relatively to file write operation, the only possibility for 16 bytes in the file is that either writer.Write(current) or writer.Write(numberbox.Value) performs one time only.
It can be cleared easily with debugging or using MessageBox.Show in both if and else branches.
But when you fixed you code, you will be wondering more because you will not be able to read data from the file since you don't know which data is written and in which order. If you begin to solve this challenge first, the problem stated above resolves itself.
